# iPhone:How can I pass argument in perform selector method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there any way to pass argument in `[self performSelector]` method in iPhone? and how many pass maximum argument in this method? if yes , then please send me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass no more than two arguments, use one of

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject
```

If you need to pass more arguments, use `NSInvocation`. Here are the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation).

UPD: Here is an `NSInvocation` example. Say, you want to send `doThis:andThis:andThis:` to `targetObject` of type `MyClass`:

```
SEL message = @selector(doThis:andThis:andThis:);
NSMethodSignature *signature  = [MyClass methodSignatureForSelector:message];
NSInvocation      *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];

[invocation setTarget:targetObject];
[invocation setSelector:message];
[invocation setArgument:&fist   atIndex:2];  // Note that you need to put &
[invocation setArgument:&second atIndex:3];  // as you send a pointer
[invocation setArgument:&third  atIndex:4];  // Also the indexing starts from 2
                                             // 0 is for target, 1 is for selector
[invocation invoke];
```

Comment: Please tell me how can i pass more than argument using NSInvocation

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:

Use

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
```

SideSwipe

Comment: Using [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:withObject:)
`- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject` you can pass up to two objects - I don't know if there is a possibility to pass more.

Comment: As stated in the other answers you can always pass more Objects by placing them in a NSDictionary or a NSArray, which you pass to the method, but you will have to change the method, you are passing to, to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You have three possibilities, overall:

```
1. – performSelector: 
2. – performSelector:withObject:
3. – performSelector:withObject:withObject:
```

the first one is no arguments at all; the second, one argument; the third, two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only one argument with performSelector

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(aSelector) withObject:(id)object];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSObject has these:

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
```

and

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject
```

You can always make anObject to be an NSArray, NSDictionary or some other custom class that will contain arguments for you

Answer (score 0):

For multiple objects - Simply create array/dictionary with your objects and pass this array/dictionary to

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aSelector) withObject:myArray];
```